# UIProgressView doesn't show progress (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, uiprogressview, dfu

I have an app which updates a BLE device using [iOSDFULibrary](https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/IOS-Pods-DFU-Library).

I have this function:

```
   func dfuProgressDidChange(for part: Int, outOf totalParts: Int, to progress: Int, currentSpeedBytesPerSecond: Double, avgSpeedBytesPerSecond: Double) {
       print("\t\(part)\t\(totalParts)\t\(progress)\t\(currentSpeedBytesPerSecond)\t\(avgSpeedBytesPerSecond)")
}
```

When the update is going on, I want my UIProgressView to move accordingly `progress` and be filled fully when the progress reaches 100.

What I have so far is:

```
@IBOutlet weak var progressView: UIProgressView!


progressView.progressViewStyle = .default
progressView.tintColor = .orange
progressView.progressTintColor = .orange
progressView.backgroundColor = .none
progressView.progress = Float(progress)
progressView.setProgress(100.0, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
func dfuProgressDidChange(for part: Int, outOf totalParts: Int, to progress: Int, currentSpeedBytesPerSecond: Double, avgSpeedBytesPerSecond: Double) {
    let progress = Float(part) / Float(total)
    progressView.setProgress(progress, animated: true)
}
```

Also I notice that you set 100 progress to ProgressView.

```
progressView.setProgress(100.0, animated: true)
```

ProgressView maximum progress is 1.0

```
open class UIProgressView : UIView, NSCoding {

    open var progress: Float // 0.0 .. 1.0, default is 0.0. values outside are pinned.

}
```

Comment: Hi @Данил Блинов and thank you so much for your comment. The thing is, I have also tried setting both ```progressView.setProgress(progress, animated: true)``` and ```progressView.setProgress(1.0, animated: true)```, but it gave no results. When put to ```1.0```, the animation just fills a half of a UIProgressView and from that moment it slows down and reaches the end slowly.